# Is this font computer modern ?

Tags: fonts

[image: extracted from 'Periodiagrams for unit root time series' -Akdi Y.]

What font is used in this document ? It looks like CM but CM is lighter than this font?

Comment: Do you have the pdf file? You can check its properties to see the fonts.

Comment: Yes, I have. Can you instruct me how i can find its font properties?

Comment: Are you using Windows? Open the file and search for some properties on some menu. What pdf reader do you use?

Comment: I am using Windows . Acrobat Reader is the pdf reader on my computer

Comment: Check document properties (maybe File or Edit menu -  I don't have win) and see more or less like this: http://blogs.adobe.com/jhsia/007.png

Comment: Yes, it is. Or it is Latin Modern, difficult to distinguish between them at low resolution.

Comment: @egreg isn't lmodern lighter than this?

Comment: `File > Document properties > Fonts thumb` in Adobe Reader. That said, if you don't have to make annotations or fill forms, SumatraPDF is much more recommended for pdf files produced by TeX, as it's faster and doesn't lock pdf files when you compile.

Comment: @Quantes How dark fonts look is highly dependent on the viewer and the OS.